# Seeking workaround for filename conflict with Visual C++ header file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

Our code includes `vector`, which includes `memory`, which includes Microsoft's `intrin.h`, but we have an `intrin.h` of our own on our include path.  Hence `memory` picks up our `intrin.h` instead of the system one, and fails to compile.

Both our `intrin.h` and Microsoft's have been around for years, but we've never had a conflict before - VS 2010 introduces a new dependency.  Moving or renaming our `intrin.h` would be a pain, and I'd rather avoid it.

Is there some way I can persuade MSVC to look in the system include directory before our own?  Editing `memory` to say:

```
#include "intrin.h"
```

rather than

```
#include <intrin.h>
```

works, but I don't want the whole team to have to modify their Visual Studio environments (and keep them modified in the face of service packs, etc.)

Any other way of working around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply adding the system include directory to the include path before your directory?

Comment: Seems like that would break his code that needs his copy of intrin.h.

Comment: @Neil: Good idea, but VS won't let me do it!  If I add "$(VCInstallDir)include" to the include path then VS changes it to ".\$(VCInstallDir)include" and it fails.  Even if I put in the full path (which is a bit nasty) it changes it to a relative path, which will then fail when someone checks out the project to a different directory depth.  Grr!  VS is being too clever for its own good!

Comment: @sean: No, it would work, because some code needs one intrin.h and some needs the other, but no code needs both.  If I have a way to control which one gets picked up, I can selectively apply it to the code that needs it.

Comment: Might want to hit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/threads and see if you are seeing expected behavior - for both the original problem and the relative include path problem.

Comment: Aha!  By prepending "$(VCInstallDir)include;" to the text of the include path in the project properties, rather than using the "<edit>" command to edit it, this works.  Thanks, Neil!

Comment: Unfortunately the details within the answer don't provide anyone else with an actual answer.  Glad to see that someone figured it out but the question and answer aren't very useful as part of an archive.